# doctrine not exists subquery

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have in a repository this code:

```
 public function getNotAssignedBy($speciality, $diploma)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('j')
        ->select('DISTINCT(j.id) id', 'j.firstName', 'j.lastName', 'j.dateBirth', 'j.sex')
        ->leftJoin('j.qualifications', 'q')
    ;


    if ($speciality) {
        $qb->andWhere('q.speciality = :speciality_id')->setParameter('speciality_id', $speciality);
    }
    if ($diploma) {
        $qb->andWhere('q.diploma = :diploma_id')->setParameter('diploma_id', $diploma);
    }

    $result = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();

    return $result;
}
```

How can I get only rows where id not exists in another entity ??

Any help. Thanks

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can achieve it with something like this:

```
    ....
    // construct a subselect joined with an entity that have a relation with the first table as example user
    $sub = $this->createQueryBuilder();
    $sub->select("t");
    $sub->from("AnotherEntity","t");
    $sub->andWhere('t.user = j.id');

    // Your query builder:
    $qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->not($qb->expr()->exists($sub->getDQL())));
```

Hope this help

Comment: `$sub = $this->createQueryBuilder();` 

`Too few arguments to function Doctrine\\ORM\\EntityRepository::createQueryBuilder(), 0 passed in and at least 1 expected`

Comment: @Unnikrishnan It may need to add at least alias parameter when $this represents Repository object

`public function createQueryBuilder($alias, $indexBy = null)`

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't comment, so I will post a fixed version of @Matteo's solution

The correct way to use `createQueryBuilder` in this case is by using `EntityManager`. See my comment in the code below.

```php
$sub = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder(); // _em stands for entity manager here. While $qb may use repositories createQueryBuilder() which requires alias 
$sub->select("t");
$sub->from("AnotherEntity","t");
$sub->andWhere('t.user = j.id');

// Your query builder:
    $qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->not($qb->expr()->exists($sub->getDQL())));
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: It will not cause an error when ran, to compare. As per my comment in the code.
Entity manager and ORM entity repo has different definitions of createQueryBuilder().
There is nothing to learn here, just a fix.