# How to convert from NOT EXISTS in normal SQL to DOCTRINE ORM

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, symfony-2.7

I am quite new to Symfony framework. I have my normal SQL as below which are tested and return the results. But I need to convert to Symfony.

```
SELECT *
FROM Car c
WHERE c.status NOT IN ('DELETED', 'HIDE')
AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT NULL
        FROM Booking b
        WHERE b.periodStart Between '2018-02-06 10:51:30' And '2018-02-06 12:51:30'
        AND b.status = 'Normal'
        AND b.car_id = c.id
    );
```

Below is my Symfony Code so far I am done.

```
$query = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Car')
                    ->createQueryBuilder('c')
                    ->where("c.status NOT IN (:DELETE , :HIDE )")
                    ->setParameter('DELETE','DELETED')
                    ->setParameter('HIDE','HIDE')
                    ->getQuery()
                    ->getResult();
```

The query run smooth and return result.  but I don't know how to add "NOT EXISTS" in the above code. Need help on that.

Comment: Left join on Booking and where is null?

Comment: Sorry didn't get it, what do u mean ?

Comment: You need to left join booking on car and select where bookin.somecolumn is not null.

Comment: Can you post for me the solution for a better view?

Comment: You would want to check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31536545/1485183

Answer (score 0):

I read through the documentation and found the solution as follow:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $query      = $em ->createQuery(
                        'SELECT c from AppBundle:Car c
                         WHERE  c.status NOT IN  (\'DELETED\', \'HIDE\')
                         AND NOT EXISTS (
                            SELECT b
                            FROM AppBundle:Booking b
                            WHERE b.periodStart Between :periodStart And :periodEnd
                            AND b.status = \'Normal\'
                            AND b.car = c.id )')
                        ->setParameter ('periodStart', $currentDateTime)
                        ->setParameter ('periodEnd', $nextTwoHourDateTime);

            $result =$query -> getResult();
```

Hope it will solve for other people